# Coordinates from Geocoding Autocomplete

Tags: here-api

We are integrating Here Autocomplete with our current typeahead feature. Currently this Autocomplete endpoint is not returning any coordinates, and to retrieve them, we must make an additional call to the Geocoding endpoint with the location id. Effectively doubling HERE calls for any one address.

Is there any way that the Autocomplete endpoint can include GPS coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

To find the corresponding geocoordinates based on free-form input, send the following GET request.

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
  &app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
  &searchtext=425+W+Randolph+Chicago

The response to the above request delivers the following high-level elements:

1) Metadata about the request
Results that match the request. 
2) The number of results depends on the completeness of the address provided.